# Super suit is getting an upgrade, but what do I not already have?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

I have a super hero from another world who can create electricity in his body and output it with general control. This character decided to make a suit to increase his powers, and succeeded. Shortly after, some big science thing exploded and sent him to this earth with his suit and powers. After saving the city from big evil things, he decided to get a suit upgrade. Problem is, his suit is already pretty good, and he's not sure what else he needs to increase his powers.

Ability stats-

He can generate electricity from his body which he can then output with varying amounts of control depending on mood, concentration, health, and stuff like that. The output can range from 5V to 100V, and from 10 Mah to 20 A. The more power outputted the more energy it consumes from him.

Suit stats-

The suit is two layers, although you could technically call it three I guess. Layer one is an advanced kevlar/gold material that conducts electricity easily and blocks bullets with minimal damage to the wearer. This is the outermost layer. Layer 2, which was not a part of the suit, is the characters skin. During the big science thing explosion, the suit melded with him so yeah. Layer three, or what was planned to be layer two, is a grid of small gold channels which would connect the skin where the electricity could be tapped into to the outer shell where it powered the electronics and shocked people who touched it. Now that this layer is under the skin, the 3000 ohms(somewhere around there) of human skin are bypassed and he has more power now. Layer one can be taken on/off, and layer 3 is mostly hidden under layer 2 for when he isn't fighting bad guys.

As for weaponry, the main weapon is his powers which he uses in hand to hand combat. It's kinda hard to beat up someone when they shock you every time you touch them. In the event that he has to resort to ranged attacks, each arm has a set of three launchers. One launcher is a grappling hook or trip wire, one is a taser powered from himself, and another launches tranquilizer darts. All of these can reload in three to five seconds, and he has a total of 6 tranquilizer cartridges. He also carries four knives, two on his belt and two in ankle holsters. He is also proficient with modern handheld weaponry like rifles and pistols.

Upgrade restrictions;

- modern technology
- under 1 thousand dollars
- not too heavy
- small enough to be worn/carried
- needs to help him in some way

So what should this super hero get to upgrade his suit?

Comment: A mobile phone? So he can watch YouTube and search Worldbuilding Stack Exchange for questions by Ceramicmrno0b about "super" "hero" "suits"?

Comment: This question doesn't have a definite answer, but can be an inexhaustible list unfortunately.

Comment: At best, this is an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609) Q that's badly asked (remember the [help/dont-ask] states not to ask questions were every answer is equally correct). At worst it's an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) Q. Raw idea generation is a poor fit to the SE format. VTC:Opinion-Based

Answer (score 4):

**Cooling**

The suit has fused, meaning he lacks many of the skin's properties to survive. To name just one, the skin is used for cooling. Our sweating is biologically revolutionary, making us excell at long duration intensive motion. Without the ability to transpire even short term intense movement can overheat and disable/kill the person.

Answer (score 2):

**Capacitors**

Sure, a maximum of 100v at 20A is decent, but your hero has discovered that it isn't always enough. To make things worse, using that much energy at once is kind of tiring. As a result, he's gonna want some lithium-ion batteries so that he can build up larger jolts and/or have reserves. These are relatively cheap, widespread, and aren't too heavy. That being said, he will need to protect them from being punctured.

Answer (score 1):

He may want devices capable of multiplying his voltage. You say he can provide 100V and 20A, but there may be a call to use 1000V at 2A, or maybe even 10,000V at 0.2A, which can be provided by several kinds of circuitry, such as a transformer or voltage multiplier. (though he may need to be careful about that kind of voltage redirecting back into himself, which may be a weakness or "oops" moment.)

He might wear a large capacitor in a backpack that he can "pump up" over time, and release the power suddenly for a larger impact. Capacitors are relatively lightweight, but bulky. They don't store as much power as a battery, but can have a very high discharge rate that batteries can't match.

Also how does he fight if the enemies starts wearing a rubber suit? That seems likely if he's been around the city for very long.

He may also want coils near his hands and feet that can be activated with his power to create a stronger magnetic field. There might be other coils that can drive a small bullet like a small rail gun.